how to use Mpchart to set a colour label in a linechart with a different dataset

i have to make these chart but i not able to add color
        LineDataSet actualDataSet = new LineDataSet(actualSales, "Actual Sales");
        actualDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
        Drawable actualDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gardient_color);
        actualDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
        actualDataSet.setFillDrawable(actualDrawable);


        LineDataSet forecastedDataSet = new LineDataSet(forecastedSales, "Forecasted Sales");
        Drawable forecastDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.forecasted_color);
        forecastedDataSet.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        forecastedDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.GREEN);
        forecastedDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
        forecastedDataSet.setFillDrawable(forecastDrawable);
        forecastedDataSet.setFillAlpha(50);

i set color on different dataset but color is overlaping on another

What's the problem? What do you expect? What did you get and how is it different from your expected outcome?
